# how to control the back button with mootools?

Tags: events, controls, mootools, back

This is how it looks for jQuery. 
How can I achieve the same thing with Mootools?

```
$(window).on("navigate", function (event, data) {
      var direction = data.state.direction;
      if (direction == 'back') {
          // do something
      }
      if (direction == 'forward') {
          // do something else
      }
});
```

Comment: Please show us your attempt, first :)

Answer (score 1):

In jQuery, this is a wrapper around `onhashchange` and `popstate`, it's not even standard jQuery but jQuery mobile etc.

There is no such wrapper out of the box in mootools-core but you can make one.

eg Cpojer wrote history.js - http://mootools.net/forge/p/history - there were a lot others.

if you want to go native, you can.

```
window.addEvent('hashchange', function(e){
  console.log(e);
  alert('hi');
});
```

etc etc.

Comment: I think native is perfect. Thanks a lot!